# gcc linker not automatically including dependency libraries

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I am in the process of updating an arm cross compiler from 4.3.3 to 4.9.4.  One issue I am seeing is that the new compiler no longer automatically includes dependent libraries.  For example:

gcc ... -L -l -lssl -lrt

works fine with the previous compiler.  If libssl needed to reference something in libcrypto, then the linker would automatically find and link with libcrypto (no -lcrypto needed).

With the new compiler, this still works, but only if libssl does not reference anything in libcrypto.  If it does, then the -lcyrpto is required.  The same issue applies to -lpthread, -ldl, etc.

Is this a change in the behavior of gcc or is something not configured properly when building gcc?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using static or dynamic libraries? For dynamic libraries, if `libssl` depends on `libcrypto`, you don't need to explicitly link `-lcrypto` as long as `libssl` itself was correctly linked, but *if you want to make direct use in your program of symbols from `libcrypto`*, then you have to explicitly link it. This is a change/intentional-regression in newer versions of binutils.

Comment: These are dynamic libraries.  The binutils are also being updated from 2.18 to 2.28.  So I think you are saying this is an intentional change in the binutils (ld) linker.

Comment: @Jay: Yes, but the binutils change only affects you if your application is using symbols from `libcrypto` without explicit `-lcrypto`. `libssl`'s use of symbols from `libcrypto` is still fine even without `-lcrypto` because the dynamic library stores its dependency info.

Comment: My experience does not match my understanding of what you stated.  I made a simple test C file with an empty main() function and compile and link with my library (-lfoo).  libfoo is linked with -lssl and -lcrypto, and indeed, objdump -x shows that the library lists libssl and libcrypto as NEEDED.  With the old compiler, my test program compiles just fine.  With the updated compiler, it does not unless I also add -lssl and -lcrypto to the C file I am compiling - even though it makes no references to those libraries.

Comment: @Jay: In that case I suspect something is wrong with your toolchain and its library paths or such. That should not happen.

Comment: Using strace, I can see that the linker (ld) is not looking in the correct place for the libraries when they are not specified with -l on the command line.  It is looking in SYSROOT/lib (twice) instead of SYSROOT/usr/lib.  The linker is not looking in the paths specified by the -L options.  When the libraries are specifically specified on the command line with -l, the linker then searches each -L path and  finds the libraries.

Comment: I have found the issue and resolved this.  The solution was to add '--with-sysroot=<new-sysroot-path>' to the binutils configure command.  With a cross compile, this results in additional SEARCH_DIR entries in the linker scripts for /usr/local/lib, /lib, and /usr/lib.  The library search paths specified by -L are not searched when looking for shared libraries specified by a DT_NEEDED entry, only those paths in the linker script LIB_SEARCH_DIRS.  See binutils/ld/emultempl/elf32.em.